# Improve raster operation in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add certain value to a raster object in R after validating if the value is NA. I need to perform this block of code 100 times repeatedly. However, I find it to be very slow. Could someone advise me to optimize this code for speed. I am amateur to programming/R. Thanks in advance.

```
for(i in 1:2077730)
{
 val<-two[i]+nerr[i]
   while(!is.na(val))
    {
     ifelse(two[i]>0,two[i]<-val,two[i]<-0)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'm guessing that the over 2 million iterations is what's making it slow.

Comment: Even worse than 2 million iterations, `val` never changes within the `while` loop, so the `while` loop never terminates. You would be better off avoiding loops entirely by vectorizing this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
idx <- two > 0
two[!idx] <- 0
two[idx] <- two[idx] + nerr[idx]
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: I tried to vectorize them. Two is a raster object. Although very big, most of the values are NA and small patch of about 15000 values needs to be modified. nerr has exactly 15000 values. Now, I need to ignore NA values in 'two' and add nerr to the other values present(Also assign 0 in place of negative numbers after adding nerr). Problem is Nerr is not a raster object. I think my problem will be fixed if I can get the cell numbers of 'two' where value!=NA. Can someone please help me.

Comment: I used nerr instead of nerr[idx] and now I am getting the required results. Thanks everyone.